# Data Attribute in jQuery is resisting to work

Tags: jquery

So i must be missing something here but after reading and looking at demo this is refusing to work. This is a basic demo to get it to work, but its still not.
I have tried many combos to get this to:

```
data('total-contract-act')
data('totalContractAct')
data('totalcontractact')
```

```js
alert( $('table.wip-detail-list').data('totalContractAct') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="wip-detail-list">
  <tr>
    <td class="col-sm-3 data-actual" data-total-contract-act="880.00">$880.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data-total-contract-act` attribute is in the `<td>`, not the `<table>`. You need to select the correct element.

```js
console.log( $('table.wip-detail-list td.data-actual').data('totalContractAct') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="wip-detail-list">
  <tr>
    <td class="col-sm-3 data-actual" data-total-contract-act="880.00">$880.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
console.log( $('table.wip-detail-list td.data-est').data('hoursEst') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="wip-detail-list">
  <tr>
    <td class="col-sm-1 icon">icon</td>
    <td class="col-sm-5 title">Hours</td>
    <td class="col-sm-3 data-actual" data-hours-act="-">-</td>
    <td class="col-sm-3 data-est" data-hours-est="195.00">195.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When i apply the same method to below it stops working. I change "td.data-actual" to "td.data-est" and .data('totalContractAct') to .data('hoursEst') and nothing.
<table class="wip-detail-list">
<tr>
<td class="col-sm-1 icon">icon</td>
<td class="col-sm-5 title">Hours</td>
<td class="col-sm-3 data-actual" data-hours-act="-">-</td>
<td class="col-sm-3 data-est" data-hours-est="195.00">195.00</td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: So i made changes and its not and is working weird [https://jsfiddle.net/james182/bnv0o53a/] any help

Comment: The selector matches multiple elements. It's looking for `data-amount-estimated` in the first match, but that one only has `data-total-contract-est`